# LDAP share attribute's value between a group members

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I want to add members to a group, then I want them to share a single attribute value that need to be changed once for it to be changed for all other members. I found a page about [effective attributes](http://info.fazenda.sp.gov.br/NXT/gateway.dll/np/090reference/200%20acm/effectiveattributes.htm?f=templates$fn=document-frame.htm$3.0).

Is it what I need and how can I apply it in FreeIPA?

Is there another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing in LDAP, as a standard, but some servers implement plugins that would do that. FreeIPA use 389ds as directory server so this plugin might be what you want http://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/design/plugins.html#virtual-attribute-service-provider-vattrsp

Comment: Yesterday I found a page that talks about class of service, but it doesn't work for me, I think I will look for the 'role' method., thanks.